# JS Скрипт перестал работать при переходе с HTTP на HTTPS

Tags: javascript, http, https

День добрый, имею на сайте важный .js скрипт, который перестал работать с переходом сайта на HTTPS. Я пытался его подогнать под https, но это не помогло, также я пробовал просто сменить http на https - и это также не помогло. Не могу разобраться где кроется проблема и как это решить.

---

```js
var scribe = require('scribe-js')(),
  app = require('express')(),
  server = require('http').Server(app),
  io = require('socket.io')(server),
  requestify = require('requestify');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
server.listen(8080);

activebots();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  updateOnline();
  getDrops();

  socket.on('newDrop', function(id) {
    requestify.post('https://localhost/api/getGame', {
        id: id
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        data = JSON.parse(response.body);
        io.sockets.emit('nd', data.text);
      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });

  });

});

function getDrops() {
  requestify.post('https://localhost/api/getdrops', {})
    .then(function(response) {
      data = JSON.parse(response.body);
      io.emit('welcomedrop', data.text);
      console.log("stats");
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

function activebots() {
  console.log("\x1b[32m", "Функция ботов сработала!");
  requestify.post('https://localhost/api/playbot', {})
    .then(function(response) {
      data = JSON.parse(response.body);
      var time = data.time;
      console.log("\x1b[32m", "Игра сыграна! ID: " + data.game + " Время: " + Number(data.time) + "мс");
      requestify.post('https://localhost/api/getGame', {
          id: data.game
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          data = JSON.parse(response.body);
          io.sockets.emit('nd', data.text);


          setTimeout(function() {
            activebots();
          }, time);

        }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          setTimeout(activebots, 50000);
        });


    }, function(err) {
      console.log("\x1b[31m", "Ошибка запроса");
      setTimeout(activebots, 50000);
    });
}
```

Comment: У вас `localhost` по https доступен?

Comment: Ваш сервер всё еще http, не имеет сертификатов и слушает порт 8080. Где вы перешли на https?